# How to display multiple $meta_boxes into separate tables

Tags: metabox

i am writing a plugin inside a class and i have created my $meta_boxes, i am able to retrieve all fields but they are duplicated and in the same table.

this is my code for add $meta_boxes

```
function ri_add_custom_box() {
    global $prefix, $meta_box, $meta_boxes;


$prefix = '_ri_custom_meta_'; // a custom prefix to help us avoid pulling data from the wrong meta box
$meta_boxes = array();

$meta_boxes[] = array(  
'id' => 'ri_meta_box_panel1', // the id of our meta box
'title' => 'Test1', // the title of the meta box
'page' => 'ri_my_page', // display this meta box on post editing screens
'context' => 'side',
'priority' => 'high', // keep it near the top
    'fields' => array( // all of the options inside of our meta box
        array(
            'name' => 'Test1:',
            'desc' => 'Test1',
            'id' => $prefix . 'Test1',
            'type' => 'text',
            'std' => ''
        ),
    )
);

$meta_boxes[] = array(  
'id' => 'ri_meta_box_panel2', // the id of our meta box
'title' => 'Test2', // the title of the meta box
'page' => 'ri_my_page', // display this meta box on post editing screens
'context' => 'side',
'priority' => 'high', // keep it near the top
    'fields' => array( // all of the options inside of our meta box
        array(
            'name' => 'Test2:',
            'desc' => 'Test2',
            'id' => $prefix . 'Test2',
            'type' => 'text',
            'std' => ''
        ),
    )
);

foreach ($meta_boxes as $meta_box) {
    new Ri($meta_box);
    add_meta_box($meta_box['id'], $meta_box['title'], array(&$this, 'ri_display_metaboxes'), $meta_box['page'], $meta_box['context'], $meta_box['priority']);
}
}
```

and this is my code for display $meta_boxes

```
function ri_display_metaboxes() {
    global $meta_box, $meta_boxes, $post;

    echo '<input type="hidden" name="ri_meta_box_nonce" value="', wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)), '" />';
    echo '<table class="form-table">';

        foreach ($meta_boxes as $meta_box) {
            foreach ($meta_box['fields'] as $field) {

            $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true);

    echo '<tr>', // create a table row for each option
                '<th style="width:20%"><label for="', $field['id'], '">', $field['name'], '</label></th>',
                '<td>';
        switch ($field['type']) {

            case 'text': // the HTML to display for type=text options
                echo '<input type="text" name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '" value="', $meta ? $meta : $field['std'], '" size="30" style="width:97%" />', '
', $field['desc'];
                break;     

            case 'textarea': // the HTML to display for type=textarea options
                echo '<textarea name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '" cols="60" rows="8" style="width:97%">', $meta ? $meta : $field['std'], '</textarea>', '
', $field['desc'];
                break;

            case 'select': // the HTML to display for type=select options
                echo '<select name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '">';
                foreach ($field['options'] as $option) {
                    echo '<option', $meta == $option ? ' selected="selected"' : '', '>', $option, '</option>';
                }
                echo '</select>';
                break;

            case 'radio': // the HTML to display for type=radio options
                foreach ($field['options'] as $option) {
                    echo '<input type="radio" name="', $field['id'], '" value="', $option['value'], '"', $meta == $option['value'] ? ' checked="checked"' : '', ' />', $option['name'];
                }
                break;

            case 'checkbox': // the HTML to display for type=checkbox options
                echo '<input type="checkbox" name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '"', $meta ? ' checked="checked"' : '', ' />';
                break;

        }
        echo     '<td>',
            '</tr>';
                }
            }
        echo '</table>';
}
```

I want to display in the first metabox Test1 and in second metabox Test2 like this
Metabox1
Test1

Metabox2
Test2

but now with this code i have

Metabox1
Test1
Test2

Metabox2
Test1
Test2

Sorry for my bad english.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You're adding the metaboxes two times. You need to verify if they already exists or better make a 1:1 relation between Metabox:Test, so Metabox1:Test1 and Metabox2:Test2. I assume that's because that you execute the code two times, once per each Metabox instance. You need to decouple the two.

Comment: I add metaboxes only one time!
I dont know how decouple the two.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe two instance of the class that adds it one time and therefore two times?

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is in your `ri_display_metaboxes()` function more specifically this line:

```
foreach ($meta_boxes as $meta_box) {
```

Which tells WordPress to render both/all metaboxes on every single metabox display callback.

to get over it you can use the `$callback_args` parameter of `add_meta_box` function

so try this:

```
function ri_add_custom_box() {
    global $prefix, $meta_box, $meta_boxes;


    $prefix = '_ri_custom_meta_'; // a custom prefix to help us avoid pulling data from the wrong meta box
    $meta_boxes = array();

    $meta_boxes[] = array(  
    'id' => 'ri_meta_box_panel1', // the id of our meta box
    'title' => 'Test1', // the title of the meta box
    'page' => 'ri_my_page', // display this meta box on post editing screens
    'context' => 'side',
    'priority' => 'high', // keep it near the top
        'fields' => array( // all of the options inside of our meta box
            array(
                'name' => 'Test1:',
                'desc' => 'Test1',
                'id' => $prefix . 'Test1',
                'type' => 'text',
                'std' => ''
            ),
        )
    );

    $meta_boxes[] = array(  
    'id' => 'ri_meta_box_panel2', // the id of our meta box
    'title' => 'Test2', // the title of the meta box
    'page' => 'ri_my_page', // display this meta box on post editing screens
    'context' => 'side',
    'priority' => 'high', // keep it near the top
        'fields' => array( // all of the options inside of our meta box
            array(
                'name' => 'Test2:',
                'desc' => 'Test2',
                'id' => $prefix . 'Test2',
                'type' => 'text',
                'std' => ''
            ),
        )
    );

    foreach ($meta_boxes as $meta_box) {
        new Ri($meta_box);
        add_meta_box($meta_box['id'], $meta_box['title'], array(&$this, 'ri_display_metaboxes'), $meta_box['page'], $meta_box['context'], $meta_box['priority'],array('fields' => $meta_box['fields']));
    }
}


function ri_display_metaboxes($post,$meta_b) {
    global $meta_boxes, $post;

    echo '<input type="hidden" name="ri_meta_box_nonce" value="', wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)), '" />';
    echo '<table class="form-table">';

        foreach ((array)$meta_b['arg']['fields'] as $field) {
            $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true);
            echo '<tr>', // create a table row for each option
                '<th style="width:20%"><label for="', $field['id'], '">', $field['name'], '</label></th>',
                '<td>';
            switch ($field['type']) {
                case 'text': // the HTML to display for type=text options
                    echo '<input type="text" name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '" value="', $meta ? $meta : $field['std'], '" size="30" style="width:97%" />', '', $field['desc'];
                    break;     
                case 'textarea': // the HTML to display for type=textarea options
                    echo '<textarea name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '" cols="60" rows="8" style="width:97%">', $meta ? $meta : $field['std'], '</textarea>', '', $field['desc'];
                    break;
                case 'select': // the HTML to display for type=select options
                    echo '<select name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '">';
                    foreach ($field['options'] as $option) {
                        echo '<option', $meta == $option ? ' selected="selected"' : '', '>', $option, '</option>';
                    }
                    echo '</select>';
                    break;
                case 'radio': // the HTML to display for type=radio options
                    foreach ($field['options'] as $option) {
                        echo '<input type="radio" name="', $field['id'], '" value="', $option['value'], '"', $meta == $option['value'] ? ' checked="checked"' : '', ' />', $option['name'];
                    }
                    break;
                case 'checkbox': // the HTML to display for type=checkbox options
                    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '"', $meta ? ' checked="checked"' : '', ' />';
                    break;
            }
            echo     '<td>',
                '</tr>';
        }
    echo '</table>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your replies.
Bainternet i am trying with your suggestions, but i have this error

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on this line
foreach ($meta_box['fields'] as $field) {
Thanks in advance.

Comment: try changing `$m[id]` to `$m['id']`

Comment: I have already tried!

Comment: ok i've updated the code, try it now

Comment: I have tried with latest changes but my metaboxes are empty now

Answer (score 0):

I have found the error!

```
foreach ((array)$meta_b['args']['fields'] as $field) {
```

instead of

```
foreach ((array)$meta_b['arg']['fields'] as $field) {
```

Answer (score 0):

How can i save post data now?

this is my code:

```
function ri_meta_save_data($post_id) {
    global $post;

    // check autosave
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    // verify nonce -- checks that the user has access
    if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['ri_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__))) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    // check permissions
    if ('page' == $_POST['post_type']) {
        if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id)) {
            return $post_id;
        }
    } elseif (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    foreach ((array)$meta_b['args']['fields'] as $field) {
        $old = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], true);
        $new = $_POST[$field['id']];

        if ($new && $new != $old) {
            update_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $new);
        } elseif ('' == $new && $old) {
            delete_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $old);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!